# Flutter Heath package requestAuthorization() always returns false

Tags: flutter, oauth-2.0, fitness

I'm going to use the flutter health package to get step data. But I can't get permission from Gmail for my app by using this method. I have already added test users to the Google console in the GCP project.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add `ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION` for getting STEP Count permission in `AndroidManifest.xml.`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
```

And then using [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) ask for permission.

```
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  final permissionStatus = Permission.activityRecognition.request();
  if (await permissionStatus.isDenied ||
      await permissionStatus.isPermanentlyDenied) {
    showToast(
        'activityRecognition permission required to fetch your steps count');
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I already did it.

Comment: You need to add the SHA finger print first in api console. You will get the SHA using a keystore file, Later on you need to test via the signed apk via that keystore file. 
Remember: You need to add the testing email as well in google api console if the app is not in production.